# using union on two tables but renaming the field

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables that have an id field with the same name. I didn't think I'd ever need to mix the two but there's one page where I need to. I can't join the tables because they both have completely separate data and no fields in common.

I can union them but the ID field is the same name and many identical numbers (which do not relate). I can't change the name in the tables but I need the field names to be different when put into a variable (using PHP).

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT date, id as id1
FROM football

UNION
SELECT date, id as id2
FROM basketball
ORDER BY date
```

But that just gives me one field (id1). I need the result to be in such a way that I can do this:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
   if (!empty($row['id1'])) {
      $id = $row['id1'];
      $sport = "football";
   } else {
      $id = $row['id2'];
      $sport = "basketball";
   }
   echo "my number is $id and I play $sport";
}
```

Comment: you could do `SELECT date, id as id1, NULL as id2 FROM football  UNION SELECT date, NULL as id1, id as id2 FROM basketball ORDER BY date`

Comment: Sean, I just tried that and it put all the ids under id1 and all the id2 fields NULL. :-/

Comment: It works for me http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/400b52/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MySQL [Union Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

> The column names from the first SELECT statement are used as the
>   column names for the results returned.

You could assign `sport` in your query:

```
SELECT date, id, 'football' as sport
FROM football    
UNION
SELECT date, id, 'basketball' as sport
FROM basketball
ORDER BY date
```

Comment: Interesting. How would that handle duplicate id's? Would it keep both? [id=1, sport='football'] and [id=1, sport='basketball'] or would it delete the second as a duplicate?

Comment: Okay, I tried it and that seems to work. I'll try it with PHP next and see if that holds up. If it does, that's an excellent solution!